# Selectable TextView with inter_word justificationMode

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, androidx

I'm trying to make a selectable TextView justified using justificationMode.
It seems that these two properties can't co-exist, because when I remove `android:textIsSelectable="true"` from the TextView, it gets justified just fine.
Here is the TextView:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_reg"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

I'm using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`, targetSdkVersion is 29 and minSdkVersion is 26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android only supports Full justification on Textview since Oreo though we have hard times to do justification on textviews with justificationMode.
But you can achive jusfication by writing a simple method inside your class.

```
public void Justify(final TextView textView) {

        final AtomicBoolean isJustify = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        final String textString = textView.getText().toString();

        final TextPaint textPaint = textView.getPaint();

        final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        textView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (!isJustify.get()) {

                    final int lineCount = textView.getLineCount();
                    final int textViewWidth = textView.getWidth();

                    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {

                        int lineStart = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(i);
                        int lineEnd = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(i);

                        String lineString = textString.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);

                        if (i == lineCount - 1) {
                            builder.append(new SpannableString(lineString));
                            break;
                        }

                        String trimSpaceText = lineString.trim();
                        String removeSpaceText = lineString.replaceAll(" ", "");

                        float removeSpaceWidth = textPaint.measureText(removeSpaceText);
                        float spaceCount = trimSpaceText.length() - removeSpaceText.length();

                        float eachSpaceWidth = (textViewWidth - removeSpaceWidth) / spaceCount;

                        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(lineString);
                        for (int j = 0; j < trimSpaceText.length(); j++) {
                            char c = trimSpaceText.charAt(j);
                            if (c == ' ') {
                                Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(0x00ffffff);
                                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) eachSpaceWidth, 0);
                                ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(drawable);
                                spannableString.setSpan(span, j, j + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            }
                        }

                        builder.append(spannableString);
                    }

                    textView.setText(builder);
                    isJustify.set(true);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

then pass your textview inside the method,

```
Textview tv = findviewbyid(R.id.text);
Justify(tv);
```

And also the best part, it is not limited to Oreo, it will work on other lower version of android.

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Text selection will also works fine with this method.

Comment: doesnt work, it completely breaks the text